# Android Studio 3.1.3 path error

Tags: android

Android studio 3.1.3  isn't running and displaying error posted below(image). I have set the jdk path in "Environment Variables" but still the problem persists. Reinstalling Android Studio after deleting the user data isn't helping. Do post other alternative way to fix this.

p.s.- I have changed jdk version from settings in Android studio to a more latest version(i.e. 1.6 to 1.8). On restart of A.S. the problem started.

I installed AS 2.1.3 removing AS 3.1.3, A.S. 2.1.3 is working fine.

### Error message:

---

Failed to create JVM:error code -1

JVM Path: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\jre

If you already have a 64 bit JDK installed, define a JAVA_HOME variable in

Computer >System properties> System settings> Environment Variables.

---

Here is an image for help:

[image]

Comment: I can't see error message, can you reattach it please?

Comment: The blue tag "enter image description here", click to see the error message

Comment: Did you check JAVA_HOME in path?

Comment: Try to download the **64-bit** Android Studio.

Comment: @Jacky i did check the JAVA_HOME path

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `Control Panel`
2. Click on `System`
3. From the left chose `Advanced system settings`
4. Click on `Environment Variable`
5. Under the `System Variable` try to find `JRE_HOME` if exist, change the `Variable Value` where you install the java and then select the jre folder, if not exist, add new variable with `JRE_HOME` for `Variable Name` and where you install the java and then select the jre folder for `Variable Value`.
6. try to run the `Android Studio`